# How to integrate Material Ui with Meteor?

Tags: meteor, material-ui

I am trying to integrate Material Ui with meteor and as a sample test tried executing the below but ended up with errors and no Idea how to resolve it. Anyone there to assist me in fixing this. Below are few detail to track.

How I installed ? --> `meteor npm install @material-ui/core`

How I Integrated code?  Through Blaze React component

**ExampleTest.js**

```
Template.ExampleTest.helpers({
  ExampleContainer() {
      return ExampleContainer;
    }
  });
```

**ExampleContainer.js**

```
const ExampleContainer = withTracker(() => {
---------
})(Example);
```

**Example.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Button } from "@material-ui/core";

class Example extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <Button color="primary">Hello World</Button> 
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Example;
```

What error did I receive ?

```
Error: In template "ExampleTest", call to `{{> React ... }}` missing `component` argument.
    at Blaze.View.<anonymous> (react-template-helper.js?hash=3fb2a2954362a4acdee8150fb77f0f500dd28206:67)
    at blaze.js?hash=cbd85c3fe14949f2d2b9a3b76334f5f0e96d553c:1934
    at Function.Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc (blaze.js?hash=cbd85c3fe14949f2d2b9a3b76334f5f0e96d553c:3769)
    at blaze.js?hash=cbd85c3fe14949f2d2b9a3b76334f5f0e96d553c:1932............
```

Any assistance on this ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using Blaze template engine. You should use React instead.
https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/components

Comment: Hi @MinhNguyen Sorry missed your response. I kept this requirement on hold as my whole project is using Blaze components and couldn't get an idea on how both Blaze and react components can be managed. Thanks for your quick support :)

Answer (score 0):

Material UI is a UI framework for use with React. It doesn't work with Blaze, and I don't think there is any way to use both Blaze and React in the same page.

To add Material UI to a Meteor/React project, install the package from the command line:

```
npm install @material-ui/core
```

And include the Roboto font in the head of your  HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" />
```

For me this just worked, with nothing special needed for Meteor.

More instructions here: https://material-ui.com/getting-started/installation/

Comment: "_I don't think there is any way to use both Blaze and React in the same page_": there is actually, see [React components in Blaze](https://guide.meteor.com/react.html#react-in-blaze)